# Forwarding from one domain to another

Tags: dns, forwarding, domain-name

my blog is running http://nooranibakerally-noor.rhcloud.com/ on openshift. I've bought a domain on godaddy as nooranibakerally.net. Now, I want to forward all request from http://nooranibakerally-noor.rhcloud.com/to http://nooranibakerally.net.

e.g. when reques http://nooranibakerally-noor.rhcloud.com/post1 is obtained, it forwards it to  http://nooranibakerally.net/post1, i.e. http://nooranibakerally-noor.rhcloud.com/ never appears in the address bar.

is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.davidsalter.com/2012/03/hosting-on-openshift.html

> To publish to a custom domain, you need to add an alias in OpenShift
>   for your application to the domain name you want it hosted at.
>
> ```
> $ rhc-ctl-app -c add-alias --alias www.somedomain.com -a <appname>
> ```
>
> To complete the process, you need to edit your DNS records and add a
>   cname pointing your domain (e.g. www.somedomain.com) to
>   -.rhcloud.com

Comment: i added this www www.nooranibakerally-noor.rhcloud.com on my DNS manager